# compare two dates for next day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some hotel records on my database. these records contain start date and end dates of how long a person stays at the hotel.

what sql command can I write to compare the two dates to see how many people only stayed in the hotel for 1 night?

thanks

sample data:

```
start date  end date   
30-JAN-16   02-FEB-16
12-FEB-16   18-FEB-16
13-FEB-16   14-FEB-16
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. Also, tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the differences the two dates which is number of days and find count on it:

```
select count(*)
from your_table
where end_date - start_date <= 1
```